# Missing Context for Method Declaration, Expected Method Body, @end Must Appear in an Objective-C Context

Tags: objective-c, interface, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Am I just missing something really dumb?

Comments are the errors:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BWStack : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (readonly, nonatomic) id topObject;

-(void)pushObject:(id)object; // Missing context for method declaration
-(id)popObject; // Expected method body

@end // @end must appear in an Objective-C context
```

Through a clean, deleting derived data, and reboot even (in that order) these errors have persisted. Put the file in a different project and no errors.

Comment: Are you including any other headers in this file?  Is there a problem with your precompiled header (.pch) file?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem was. I rolled back to a slightly earlier version of the code I had under revision control and the errors didn't pop up. I'm assuming that I had a strange character or something somewhere in another header?